# Unable to tag question using libvirt

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

I have a question asked recently here:

[Unable to start libvirtd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/310490/unable-to-start-libvirtd)

which I am unable to tag with [libvirt](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/libvirt) If I tag it, it disappears when the question is up on AU. What is going wrong here?

Comment: libvirt and virtulaization pointing to same tag . So no need to use it separatly

Comment: @Tachyons Provide that as an answer. ;) Btw, synonyms can be found on the tag's page. See for this case http://askubuntu.com/tags/virtualization/synonyms

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[libvirt](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/libvirt) and [virtualization](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/virtualization) tags are synonyms: https://askubuntu.com/tags/virtualization/synonyms. So, as [Tachyons](http://meta.askubuntu.com/users/39372/tachyons) said in one comment, no need to use it separatly.

See https://askubuntu.com/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms:

> **What happens when a question is asked using a synonym?**
>
> Any tags that match active synonyms will be automatically and silently changed from their original as-entered form to the tag that the synonym points to.
>
> This also increments a synonym counter, which you can view at [/tags/synonyms](https://askubuntu.com/tags/synonyms) to evaluate the effectiveness (or ineffectiveness) of the synonyms that are in place.